# devstack -"Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 "

Tags: python, devstack

i install the devstack in centos7 which run on physical machine.i meet the question that "Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 ".The log is too long to post all.so i just post the keys.

```
2017-11-12 14:03:33.612 |   Downloading pyperclip-1.5.27.zip
2017-11-12 14:03:33.909 |     Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
2017-11-12 14:03:33.909 |     No protocol specified
2017-11-12 14:03:33.909 |     Traceback (most recent call last):
2017-11-12 14:03:33.909 |       File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
2017-11-12 14:03:33.909 |       File "/tmp/pip-build-a6kle5/pyperclip/setup.py", line 8, in <module>
2017-11-12 14:03:33.909 |         version=__import__('pyperclip').__version__,
2017-11-12 14:03:33.909 |       File "pyperclip/__init__.py", line 101, in <module>
2017-11-12 14:03:33.909 |         copy, paste = determine_clipboard()
2017-11-12 14:03:33.909 |       File "pyperclip/__init__.py", line 63, in determine_clipboard
2017-11-12 14:03:33.909 |         import gtk  # check if gtk is installed
2017-11-12 14:03:33.909 |       File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/gtk-2.0/gtk/__init__.py", line 64, in <module>
2017-11-12 14:03:33.909 |         _init()
2017-11-12 14:03:33.909 |       File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/gtk-2.0/gtk/__init__.py", line 52, in _init
2017-11-12 14:03:33.909 |         _gtk.init_check()
2017-11-12 14:03:33.909 |     RuntimeError: could not open display
2017-11-12 14:03:33.909 |     
2017-11-12 14:03:33.909 |     ----------------------------------------
2017-11-12 14:03:34.097 | Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-a6kle5/pyperclip/
2017-11-12 14:03:34.297 | +inc/python:pip_install:1                  exit_trap
2017-11-12 14:03:34.300 | +./stack.sh:exit_trap:493                  local r=1
2017-11-12 14:03:34.302 | ++./stack.sh:exit_trap:494                  jobs -p
2017-11-12 14:03:34.305 | +./stack.sh:exit_trap:494                  jobs=
2017-11-12 14:03:34.307 | +./stack.sh:exit_trap:497                  [[ -n '' ]]
2017-11-12 14:03:34.310 | +./stack.sh:exit_trap:503                  '[' -f '' ']'
2017-11-12 14:03:34.313 | +./stack.sh:exit_trap:508                  kill_spinner
2017-11-12 14:03:34.315 | +./stack.sh:kill_spinner:407               '[' '!' -z '' ']'
2017-11-12 14:03:34.318 | +./stack.sh:exit_trap:510                  [[ 1 -ne 0 ]]
2017-11-12 14:03:34.320 | +./stack.sh:exit_trap:511                  echo 'Error on exit'
2017-11-12 14:03:34.320 | Error on exit
```

i don't know how to deal it.dose some have the idea?
thanks a lot.

Comment: Are you by chance working remotely, e.g. via `ssh`?

Comment: @bgse yes I use TeamViewer to control the pc.